# Remove "border" from custom style radio

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="gender-options">
<label title="item1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> 
<img /> 
Musko   
</label>
<label title="item2">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
<img />
Zensko
</label>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
div.gender-options > label > input {
visibility: hidden;
color: #b8b9bd;
}

div.gender-options > label > img {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px;
height:20px;
width:20px;
border: 0px;
background: url("../img/icons/checkbox.png");
}

div.gender-options > label > input:checked +img {  
background: url("../img/icons/checkbox_checked.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-size:20px 20px;
border: 0px;
}
```

Everything works fine, but I am having a problem with some border, if I remove `background` it will be just a blank border; I just want to to remove that border.

Here is the image (white border over my blue checkbox):

[image: image1]

Comment: Pls add your code in jsfiddle.net and update question with a link. so we can understand your issue exactly

Comment: It is not show in code you given. https://jsfiddle.net/frga9f4d/

Comment: Sorry here is jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/v33bd1eg/
I wanna remove the the gray border and have my blue checkbox image only

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `outline: none;` property. Also, a demo would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

According to me this border is coming on your radio button so `visibility:hidden` is not working fine for you here remove your radio button with following css:

```
div.gender-options > label > input {
  position:absolute;
  clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

`Clip` property will hide your radio input and that problem will not exist but remember `clip` property will only work with `position:absoulte` property.